# Using on_change() method in bokeh (python code)

Tags: python, bokeh

The purpose of the below code is to generate `TextInput()` boxes based on an input in a `TextInput()` box and extract values from the new `TextInput()` boxes
The problem is that I am having difficulty understanding the `on_change()` function. After typing into the first box I get a number of boxes (which I will call 'generated box').
I am able to print 'Printing' whenever I type into a generated box so I know that the `on_change()` method is working in a loop for all the generated boxes but I have been unable to extract the User input in any of the generated boxes.

```
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, TextInput
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, row, column 
curdoc().clear()
NR=TextInput() #Input no. of rows in this
N=[] #stores the TextInput boxes NR times
value=0
def PushSes(x):
      rowe = row(x)
      curdoc().add_root(rowe)

def update(attr,new,old):
      global value
      global N
      value1= int(NR.value)
      for i in range (value1):
            N.append(TextInput()) #N stores the TextInput boxes

      for i in N:
            i.on_change('value',update1)

      curdoc().clear()
      PushSes(N)

def update1(attr,new,old):
      print('Printing')
NR.on_change('value',update)
val=[] #stores value from the first row
session=push_session(curdoc())
PushSes(NR)
session.show()
session.loop_until_closed()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem -

```
def update1(attr,new,old):
      print('Printing')
      print(old)
```

In a loop `old` has the values and prints in order of the typing. Thanks to @bigreddot for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` parameter passed to `update1` by Bokeh when it calls the callback, has the new value of the text box.